# Center Bootstrap form-control to center of browser

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, form-control

Im trying to center the form control to the center of my website, but for some reason the CSS doesnt apply to the form-control, but it applies to everything else in the div...

This my HTML:

```
<div id="search">
    <h2 style="color:deepskyblue">Enter battle-tag</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.TextBox("profileId", null, new { @class = "form-control" }); <br />
                    <p style="color:red">Replace the "#" in your battle-tag with an "-"</p>
                    <p style="color:red"> Search is Case-Sensitive </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Find Player </button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}


.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}


input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

#search{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-left:10%;
}
```

Obviously the Bootstrap.css is default, I havent touched it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can centre a element by rendering it as inline-block, and set parent's text-align attribute to center.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">This should be in the middle</div>
</div>
```